# Managing Git with Sublime Text Salesforce IDE plugin (HaoIDE)

Tags: workflow, git, sublime, haoide

I am setting up our Saleforce GIT repo and trying to plan out a solid workflow, but I'm unsure how to make it work with the [Sublime Text 3: Salesforce IDE plugin](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Salesforce%20IDE) ([Refactored to HaoIDE](https://github.com/xjsender/haoide)) because it creates a separate *(uniquely named)* project folder (based on a package.xml file).

My first thought was to have to branches, one for production and one for development/sandbox, and then I would create bug and feature branches from the development branch (which represents my sandbox environment). For example:

```
production o-------o---------------------------------------------------o----------
                    \                                                 /
development          o-------o----------------o------------o---------o
                         \    \              /            /
new-feature               \    o--------------o----------o
                           \               /
hotfix                      o-------------o
```

> The plugin has a settings file setup like this:

```
"projects":
{
    "Production":
    {
        "allowed_packages":
        [
        ],
        "default": false,
        "login_url": "https://login.salesforce.com",
        "password": "********",
        "production": "https://login.salesforce.com",
        "sandbox": "https://test.salesforce.com",
        "security_token": "Ucv1d984sdfbbg64py",
        "username": "email@company.com"
    },
    "Sandbox":  <<---- These cannot be the same, i.e. "Project-Name"
    {
        "allowed_packages":
        [
        ],
        "default": true,
        "login_url": "https://test.salesforce.com",
        "password": "********",
        "security_token": "h94jhjhyn98bvtre7wg4ewtrh",
        "username": "email@company.com.dev"
    }
},
"workspace": "C:/projects/salesforce"
```

So with this setup my repo would have two separate folders. With 2 folders I can never actually merge one into the other. One additional thought I had was to make orphan branches so that each branch only has 1 folder but I'm not sure how this would look long term considering I still can't merge one branch into the other.

**Note**: Once the `package.xml` is loaded and the packaged is downloaded both the *Production* and *Sandbox* folders will have a `.config` folder with settings specific to the environment they're connected to which I forsee causing more issues so I plan to add `.config` folder to the `.gitignore` file

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what question you're asking, but I'm happy to help try and get you setup.  We use MM/ST3 and git together with good success.  MM definitely wants to create a new folder when you create a new project and it can be confusing.

Comment: Sweet! So what is your Git Flow then because at the moment with both project folders I essentially have 2 environments in one repo or branch. For example my master branch would have `Production` and `Sandbox` folders even though they both represent the same codebase, does that make sense?

Comment: In your local filesystem typically, you have one canonical set of metadata and directories. When you switch branches in git, that filesystem is overwritten and the truth resides in git.

Comment: Is this something you can reformat into an answer or solution? I'm not sure I understand the comment here as to what I need to do for a clear functioning git flow when using this ST3: Salesforce IDE

Comment: So, I think I see what you're getting at.  Here's my advice: create a MM project from the production environment, and optionally create a git repo from it.  But set this aside.  Treat this as a backup only.  Instead, create your entire git flow around the sandbox environment.  Use whatever "flow" you want and create your branches/bugfixes/etc. off of the sandbox metadata.  So, in your diagram above, remove the "production" swimlane.  The git repo that you really care about is the sandbox repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Using the comments provided I'm going to attempt to submit a response for documentation until someone else provides a better solution. Also SublimeApex has been converted to HaoIDE (the steps are basically the same)*

## Setting up <s>SublimeApex</s> HaoIDE

To start, once you install <s>[SublimeApex](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Salesforce%20IDE)</s> [HaoIDE](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/haoide) from [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation) and restart Sublime Text, you first need to setup your user settings as mentioned in the question above (this will establish your authentication to for any environment you wish to connect to)

[image: Setup User Settings]

If you switch to any of these projects then a folder with a `.config` folder will appear in your workspace for authentication purposes

[image]
[image]

> **NOTE:** you **can** create as many *or as little* projects from these connections as you would like. Although you can make a project for both Sandbox and Production you don't have to.

## Setting up your PROJECT package

Next, simply add a new project for your sandbox environment which will fetch the environment from your *active* project (in this case, Sandbox)

[image]

This will build a default `package.xml` that will package your active environment into a `.zip` and then unpack them into the projects workspace or default workspace if there is not one declared for that project. In Sublime you should see the new folder like this.

[image]

## Setting up your CUSTOM/REPO package

Here's the trick. If the package you pulled down is complete for your purposes then you will skip this step. For me, I want to include things like **sObjects and Custom Fields** so that they can be used for deployment to other environments as well. So I need to make a separate *custom* package for this environment, do so by either of the following:

1. right-clicking on the sandbox folder, `SublimeApex > Create Package.xml`
   [image]
2. copy the current `package.xml` and move to the root of your project directory *(preferred)*

> **TIP:** *Where ever your custom `package.xml` file is when you **retrieve** it is where the fetched package will be*

#### Setup your custom package.xml

Since, for this example, we want sObjects and custom Fields we need to include the following:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomField</name>
</types>
```

Then **save** right-click anywhere in the file (make sure the correct environment/project is still active), and select **SublimeApex > Retrieve Package.xml**

[image]

Once your package has been fetched you should see a new folder `project-name-timestamp], for this example I got`Sandbox-201412171532`and within it is the`src` file containing all the package components I want to version control in my repo

[image: Custom Package with timestamp]

NOW, that I have the `src` folder containing everything I want to be part of my repo I will move that folder into my Company Name folder like so:

[image: Company Folder]

## Setup GIT Repository

With this src file you can now setup `git init` and structure your branches however you need. Most likely something as described in the question above. The repository is one thing, the environments are another. **What exist in your git repository is what actually exist** because it is version controlled.

You can deploy anything from within this repository using SublimeApex context menu. While in a file or by clicking any folder within the sidebar, select `SublimeApex > Deploy to Server`

[image]

Hopefully this tutorial can help you get started with managing your Salesforce repository